# Page not found not returning 404. (return 200)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

[image]I am using react router dom v6. When url not found it's going for Page Not Found component. But is returning 200 status in Network. It should be return 404 for page not found.

<Route path="/page-not-found" element={} status={404}/>
<Route path="*" element={} status={404}/>